# BulkInsert: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I have 2 entities: Project and StepImplementation. StepImplementation has a FK to the Project table. 
[image: Tables schema]

I need to add a new Project with 500 steps to the DB. If I use a simple EntityFramework - I have no issues, but as far as I have 500 steps in the SQL Profiler I observe 500 inserts. So I'm trying to add a new Project with a bunch of steps with [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/).

```
public Project CreateProjectCopy(Project project)
{
    var newProject = this.repositoryScope.Projects.Value.Add(new Project()
    {
        Name = project.Name,
        BddFrameworkType = project.BddFrameworkType,
        Domain = project.Domain,
        IsActive = project.IsActive,
        IsPrivate = project.IsPrivate,
        ProjectKey = this.GenerateProjectKey(),
        SavingMode = project.SavingMode
    });

    this.repositoryScope.Projects.Value.SaveChanges();

    var checkProjectExists = this.repositoryScope.Projects.Value.GetFirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == newProject.Id);
    var steps = project.StepImplementations.Select(s => new StepImplementation()
    {
        DocComment = s.DocComment,
        StepImplementationText = s.StepImplementationText,
        Project = checkProjectExists
    }).ToList();
    this.repositoryScope.StepImplementations.Value.AddRange(steps);
    this.repositoryScope.StepImplementations.Value.SaveChanges();

    newProject.Branches = this.treeManager.CopyAll(project);

    return newProject;
}

public virtual void AddRange(List<T> entities)
{
    this.context.BulkInsert(entities, new BulkInsertOptions { SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, BatchSize = entities.Count() });
}
```

On the AddRange method I get an error: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

> FK_dbo.StepImplementation_dbo.Project_Project_Id". The conflict
>   occurred in database "RelimeDB", table "dbo.Project", column 'Id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

But I intentionally added checkProjectExists variable to check that the project exists in the database. Also before addRange method, I check newly added Project via Sql Manager Studio and it's available. So why BulkInsert cannot add the steps, if pure EntityFramework can?

Comment: Your `StepImplementations` class likely has a "ProjectId" property on it, try setting that instead of/as well as the `Project` property. I'd guess that `BulkInsert` doesn't look at child objects.

Comment: Also, you should really be checking `checkProjectExists` for null before proceeding, or, if you know it will always be there, using `First` or `Single` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: In my StepImplementation class Project is virtual: `public virtual Project Project { get; set; }` I cannot set Project_Id in this case, I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful,

[EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) is a very good library for some basic scenarios but fail at supporting more complex scenario.

By example, the library **DO NOT** support:

- Complex Association
- Complex Type
- Navigation Properties (Like in your case)
- TPC
- TPT
- Output Identity Value

And some other stuff

In your case, it probably doesn't support navigation properties and try to insert the Project_Id column with either a NULL value, or it's not part of the insert statement (So use default value = Null).

There is currently three major library supporting Bulk Insert

See: [Entity Framework Bulk Insert Library](http://entityframework.net/bulk-insert)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is **NOT** free but however support everything you may need for performing BulkOperations

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```